# Giving the object to create as parameta in constuctor

Tags: java, constructor

sorry for the title I don't know how to say that.

So basically what I want to do is the following:

```
public class TestClass {

    private final String name;

    public TestClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public TestClass(TestClass test) {
        this = test;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

So create a class where you can give an object from itself in the constructor

I don't know if that is possible at all.
The problem I have is that I have multiple objects that extend from this class and I want a simple way to pass them to the next class

so when I have 2 classes

1. TestClass2 extends TestClass
2. TestClass3 extends TestClass

and I want to create an instance of the testclass3 from the testclass2 one.
they both should have the same name from testcalss

currently, I am doing that like that:

```
private class TestClass2 extends TestClass{

    private final String anotherName;

    public TestClass2(String name, String anotherName) {
        super(name);
        this.anotherName= anotherName;
    }

    private void createTest3(String whatever) {
        new TestClass3(this, whatever);
    }
}

private class TestClass3 extends TestClass{

    private final String whatever;

    public TestClass3(TestClass test, String whatever) {
        super(test.getName());
        this.whatever = whatever;
    }
}
```

In my case, my base class has not just a name but a lot more values that I then have to submit!

I hope you kinda understand what I want to say. Again sorry I explained that very bad :D

And thank you all thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Are you asking how to create a [copy constructor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-constructor)?

Comment: If you want to put an object as parameter in the constructor you need to have an attribute in that class of that object type. You are using just one attribute in that constructor but expecting to save two.